# Getting Error Apple push notification OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, apple-push-notifications

> OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError (SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server session ticket A):

Integrate the library for apple push notification Houston gem. Since last two months, It was working smoothly, But now getting that error in the application.

Tries many solutions to resolve the issues.

Also tried with new certificate pem file but getting same error..sometimes it is working

Please help to solve the issues.

Comment: Did you find any solution to that?

Answer (score 0):

The error strictly says that you're using wrong APNS certificate. It may be expired, or it's just an old certificate's type (created prior to Dec, 2015).

A year ago Apple introduced new *universal* certificates, and today it supports only them. So you need to create a new *universal* certificate to make push notifications work again.

On apple.com certificate has .p12 extension, you might convert it in some incorrect way.

Another gem I use to send apns notifications (rpush) is able to use p12 certificates with no worries. You may also send some test push using Rpush gem to figure out if it is Houston's problem or it's certificate's issue.